# ESLint - "Expected indentation of 0 tabs but found 4 spaces." when trying to override airbnb config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm trying to set up ESLint for my project via VSCode

I installed it and this is my `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "mocha": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "flowtype",
        "flowtype-errors",
        "import",
        "promise",
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": 0,
        "indent": ["error", "tab"]
    }
}
```

But when I look at some line like this:

```
export function increment() {
    return {
        type: INCREMENT_COUNTER
    };
}
```

I get these errors:

```
[eslint] Expected indentation of 0 tabs but found 4 spaces. (indent)
[eslint] Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 4 spaces. (indent)
```

I think there is some conflict between the value I tried to override and between airbnb's configuration. I'm trying to set indentation to 1 tab instead of just 2 spaces

I used this boilerplate for my project:
`https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate`

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#extending-configuration-files) talks about how to extend the .eslintrc file... Looks like you're overriding the "indent" rule.

Comment: It looks like your code is using spaces 4 spaces instead of the tab character.  If you convert your 4 spaces to a tab character it should work. You'll have to disable/override the [`no-tabs`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-tabs) rule too, though.

Comment: You could generate an `.eslintrc.js` from scratch running `~/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/.bin/eslint --ini`.